# How to connect to my new mysql DB on the cloud?

Tags: mysql, cloud

I'm trying to figure out the whole idea of databases in a cloud environment, or more correctly - data management on the cloud. I've recently created a test database on what is called a [mysql cloud](http://xeround.com/cloud-database-comparison/) env. and I'm trying to connect to it - anyone have any experience with this? I get connection errors. After that, I'm wondering what is the best way to populate the database with the data from my old MySQL. Any tips are welcome! Thanks :)

Comment: what sort of connection errors?

Comment: Providing errors and useful information is definitely overrated.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding connection errors: what errors?

On how to move data:

- export data (use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html))
- upload to server (ftp?)
- import (use [mysql command line](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html))